# Variable interpolation in expect

Tags: bash, expect

This expect script cannot interpolate or assign the /bin/date to ydate. 
keeps on throwing errors. I tried the backticks and that did not work.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
        ydate=$(date -d 'yesterday' "+%Y.%m.%d")
        file="casper_${ydate}.csv"
        spawn scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -oport=666 $file casper@casper-server:/spooky/outgoing
        set pass "foofoofoo"
        expect {
        password: {send "$pass\r"; exp_continue}
                  }
```

Comment: Try using public-key authentication and dispensing with `expect`.

Comment: Expect is an extension of Tcl. More information at http://www.tcl.tk

Comment: take a look at [*sexpect*](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) with which you can write "Expect" scripts with only shell code so you don't have to learn the new Tcl language.

Answer (score 2):

Expect has 2 ways to get the date without needing to call out to an external program:

1. Tcl's [`clock` command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/clock.htm)

   ```
   set ydate [clock format [clock seconds] -format "%Y.%m.%d"]
   ```
2. [Expect](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/expect.1.html)'s `timestamp` command

   ```
   set ydate [timestamp -format "%Y.%m.%d"]
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Update: use [Glenn Jackman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50633045/1126841) (if you don't configure public-key authentication) instead of this to avoid having to use `exec`.

---

You have to use `expect`'s syntax, not the shell's, as this is not a shell script.

```
set ydate [exec date -d "yesterday" "+%Y.%m.%d"]
set file "casper_${ydate}.csv"
```

Comment: Good to know about this style of `expect` coding, thanks for sharing.

Comment: Single quotes have no meaning in Tcl, so this is like you're calling `date -d "'yesterday'" ...` -- either use no quotes around "yesterday" as it's a single word that doesn't need quoting, or use "double quotes" or {braces}... Fixed.

Comment: Thanks. It's been 20 years since I last wrote any actual Tcl.

Comment: It has a fond place in my heart